# how can i select row's index from multi select

Tags: mysql

how can I Derive the query..?

Create Table Query:

```
CREATE TABLE `account_list` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nick` char(12) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `sponsor` char(12) DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `nick` (`nick`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

Example table data:

```
ID      NICK    SPONSOR
1       A       NULL
2       B       C
3       C       NULL
4       D       C
```

```
SELECT a.id, a.nick,b.sponsor
FROM account_list a (select b.sponsor from account_list b)
```

then, I wanted some like this:

```
SELECT id, nick, sponsor FROM `account_list` ....

ID      NICK    SPONSOR
1       A       
2       B       3
3       C       
4       D       3
```

look the sponsor row.
printed C is 3.

how can I select look like this?

Comment: *"how can i select row's index from multi select"*  Question is not totally clear you mean `row_number()` ?  More or less like this -> https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ksLPVrjoVhypWnrQiCNAz2/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query was almost right(I think) the sub query where clause should reference nick

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t
(ID  int,    NICK varchar(1),   SPONSOR varchar(1));
insert into t values
(1    ,   'A'    ,   NULL),
(2    ,   'B'    ,   'C'),
(3    ,   'C'    ,   NULL),
(4    ,   'D'    ,   'C');

SELECT id, nick,sponsor,
       (select b.id 
        from t as b 
        WHERE a.sponsor= b.nick and a.sponsor is not null
          )
FROM t as a
; 

+------+------+---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|    1 | A    | NULL    |                                                                                             NULL |
|    2 | B    | C       |                                                                                                3 |
|    3 | C    | NULL    |                                                                                             NULL |
|    4 | D    | C       |                                                                                                3 |
+------+------+---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: ok. solved thx! it is 100% wanted Query. 
To reinforce a bit more, ```(select b.id 
        from t as b 
        WHERE a.sponsor= b.nick and a.sponsor is not null
          ) sponsor```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using account_list for left  join

```
SELECT a.id, a.nick, b.id sponsor
from  account_list a 
left join account_list b ON b.nick = a.sponsor
```

Comment: half success! but I want to get to real mach data.

Comment: your comment have not sense to me ..  you have error?  show the exact error message ... wrong result  .. update your question add the code you are using, you actual result and your real expected  result

Comment: Nearly, left join account_list b ON a.nick = b.sponsor  should be left join t b ON a.sponsor = b.nick

Comment: @P.Salmon thanks    answer  updated  with proper join clause

Comment: @scaisEdge thx! 
It was so good too. but ```SELECT id, nick,sponsor,
       (select b.id 
        from t as b 
        WHERE a.sponsor= b.nick and a.sponsor is not null
          )
FROM t as a
; ``` that is 100% wanted query thx all of you